# What is the interior of $S^n$

Tags: general-topology

Is the interior of $S^n$ empty or is it all of $S^n$?  My reasoning is that given any point on $S^n$, any open ball around the point cannot be contained in $S^n$, so it should be empty.  However, it's all of $S^n$ according to my book.

Comment: Interior as a subset of which topological space?

Comment: Well $S^n \subset \mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, right?  Simply applying the definition of interior point, it seems to me no point of $S^n$ can be an interior point.  Where am I going wrong?

Comment: It is true that you could consider $S^n$ as a subspace of $\mathbb R^{n+1}$, but it need not be thought of as such.  The $n$-sphere is a topological space in its own right.  To talk about the interior of a set, you have to know in which topological space you are working.  In the one-point topological space $\{0\}$, the interior of $\{0\}$ is $\{0\}$, but as a subspace of $[0,1]$ with its standard topology, the interior of $\{0\}$ is empty.  So, can you find further context about what your book is saying?  The interior of $S^n$ as a subset of which topological space?

Answer (score 4):

To emphasize what is implicit in previous comments and answers: It makes no sense to speak of the interior of a set $A$ unless one also specifies a topological space $X$ with $A\subseteq X$.  So we should speak of the interior of $A$ *in* $X$.  This interior depends on both $A$ and $X$, so if you change $X$ while leaving $A$ unchanged, you may very well find a changed interior.